# increment fields values of struct in matlab

Tags: matlab, field, structure

I want to create a struct with a field that the number of elements changes according to the value of `n` to be `n(n-1)/2`.

E.g., if `n=4`, `s=struct('name', { {1,2}, {1,3}, {1,4}, {2,3}, {2,4}, {3,4} })`.

I wrote this code but it generates only the last values of the loop:

```
function [ b ] = Bwcl( cl )
n=size(cl,1);
for k=1:n-1
     for i=k:n-1
         b(k).name={num2str(k),num2str(i+1)};
     end
end
```

Comment: Your first for loop is useless because the variable "j" is only set to a single value.

Comment: @DomDev Good spot. Removed that erroneous code. In the original post before the edit, the OP commented this out. I forgot to remove that code all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a counter to your code. The problem was the b(k), which rewrote at the same location multiple times. With b(counter) shown below, it works.

```
counter = 0;
n=size(cl,1);
for k=1:n-1
     for i=k:n-1
         counter = counter + 1;
         b(counter).name={num2str(k),num2str(i+1)};
     end
end
```

Comment: That's it !! I didn't figure out what index to assign to b(?) and now number of elements is incremented :) thank u very much

Answer (score 2):

DomDev answered the question correctly.  However, I'd like to show you a way without loops:

```
n = 4;
ind = nchoosek(1:n, 2);
D = num2cell(ind, 2);
s = struct('name', D);
```

The second line of code uses [`nchoosek`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nchoosek.html) to find all unique combinations of pairs from 1 up to `n`.  This produces a matrix where each row is a unique pair of values. We then transform this into a cell array using [`num2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html) where each pair of values occupies one cell in the cell array, such as how you have presented it above.  We then feed this cell array into `struct` to produce the final desired structure.

If you prefer a one-liner (two if you count declaring `n`):

```
n = 4;
s = struct('name', num2cell(nchoosek(1:n, 2), 2));
```

Comment: Perfect !! didn't meet these commands before, it's good to learn, thank you both so much :)

Comment: You're very welcome. It is common practice here on StackOverflow to accept the answer that helped you the best if your issue is solved. Click on the checkmark icon at the top of any of our posts, to the left below the up and down voting arrows to signify this. Thanks and good luck!

Comment: It's done. once I earn enough reputation I'll vote useful. Thank u and good continuation.